# How to annotate "@readonly-but-modified-internally" members / properties in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, readonly, jsdoc, jsdoc3

JSDoc has a [`@readonly` doclet tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-readonly.html):

> The @readonly tag indicates that a symbol is intended to be read-only.

For example:

```
/**
* The name of the represented principal
* @member {string}
* @readonly
*/
this.name = primaryName;
```

However, what I *really* want to communicate and document is that public consumers should *treat* the property as read-only - but the member is *not* constant.

Internal code can, and does, modify such members: the read-only doclet tag is for the API consumers. (And if the API is used incorrectly, shame on them! - but not my concern.)

```
/**
* Update the security token information.
* (This is a made-up example!)
*/
this.updateToken = function (token) { this.name = token.name; }
```

Is there a good way to express this concept in JSDoc (tags)? In particular,

*What is a good way to express "it is expected that internal code modifies this read-only member"?*

---

Without writing such explicitly, aside from doclet tags, in the documentation of course.

I was originally hoping JSDoc would trivially accept "@readonly private" or similar, but such is not the case.. The issue with using a custom tag is that such is introduced locally, having no imminent external meaning or application in the standard templates.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is nothing like multiple tags.

like **“@readonly,private” is not there.**

So you can use either of *@readonly* or *@private* but what you are looking for is something not possible/available currently (as per my knowledge).

Answer (score 3):

As per my opinion **@readonly** is best in this case. whether it modified internally, it will be read only for external user.